# android AudioTrack measuring volume level

Tags: android

how to measure volume level of AudioTrack in android .I got few AudioTrack initialised and running simultaniously in my app , i want to measure all AudioTracks volume level, ie at what volume level its playing not the default volume of the player

is there any method to calculate volume level per second out of 10(say)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes - the audio format that you provide to AudioTrack is raw PCM, so each sample contains the wave amplitude at the current time slice.

Since the audio wave alternates between positive and negative, you need the absolute value of each sample (`Math.abs()`).

An average of all the samples in a particular second would be a good start for calculating the current volume level. The minimum is always 0, and the maximum is according to the sample depth (8, 16 or more bits).

If you want a more smooth average, you can smoothen it by:
total_average = 0.9 * total_average + 0.1 * last_average.